# MySQL table "doesn't exist" error

Tags: windows, mysql, restore, sql, reinstall

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate x64. After reinstalling OS copied back whole MySQL data directory to `C:/Programdata`. But now when i'm trying to open some table from restored db's with Navicat it shows me http://prntscr.com/2s9wl error. I don't know what to do. can anyone help me with teamviewer?

Comment: Stop asking people for help via team viewer. It's rude. If you need help, pay for mysql support, don't beg on a site.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install SQL secondhand, (with XAMPP or something?) And if not, and it was the official installer, make sure you GOT ALL OF THE files and not just program data. You really do need everything. I hope you still have the original files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the same version as before reinstalling OS? If not, you should run [mysql_upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-upgrade.html).

Comment: it's the same version